# How to engage the user while waiting for Instant Payment Notification from PayPal

Tags: workflow, payment

I am creating a donation platform which will be using PayPal as a payment gateway. When the payment is made, the donor will be redirected back to the platform and I want to show confirmation there as soon as the platform is notified by Instant Payment Notification from PayPal.

The problem is that the IPN is sent only [10 seconds after the payment](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1063&actp=LIST) is made. What would be the best way to make the donor busy while waiting for the confirmation?

Donors suppose to donate multiple times, so it should be not too boring to them, neither too repetitive.

P.S. I know that it would be possible to use Payment Data Transfer (PDT) instead of IPN, but I want to avoid it, because of more demanding configuration on the donation receiver's side.

Comment: I'm interested in answers.  Anecdotally we have a series of waiting animations that we cycle through, but while this isn't a terrible solution, it's not a particularly clever one, and bored users refresh or nav away which makes everything worse.

Comment: So donors are donating multiple times in a single session? Are they navigating to different causes, then selecting and donating?

Comment: It could be in a single session, or in multiple sessions. The thing is that they shouldn't be bored to wait for 10 seconds after any payment.

Answer (score 2):

What if you rewarded each donation with a joke or a quote? Perhaps another section of an interesting photograph. If the user chooses to only make a single donation, but would still like to reveal what you intend to show them, offer them a quick puzzle to solve.